# What justifies a new answer in terms of difference from existing ones

Tags: discussion

I posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30884887/4923629), and then someone else posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30886212/4923629), which as far as i can see is practically an exact replica of mine with minor(not asked for by original poster) changes.

So I was just wondering what the prerequisites were for posting similar answers ?

Comment: Looks like the answer was deleted...

Comment: What justifies your answering an off topic question?  Gah, these command line application questions are constantly skirting topic-ness.  It causes me heartburn, I tell ya.

Answer (score 2):

A vast majority of the time, both of you had the same solution and were writing it at the same time, it's just one was slightly faster.

More often the phrasing of the answer is slightly different so it can be beneficial to have answers that explain concepts in different ways.  If answers are almost word-for-word duplicates, then it is customary for the author of the 2nd post to delete their answer (which is probably what happened here), but no one is under any obligation to do so.

Beyond the parallel writing efforts (so a duplicate answer was posted hours or days after the initial), there are other cases some innocent, some not.

- Different explanation (same case as I mentioned above - someone felt they had a better way to explain a concept)
- They didn't see a duplicate answer, just saw a post that they could answer
- Rep sniping - someone is trying to post answers to get upvotes regardless of existing answers.

I am ignoring plagiarism because that is basically the same idea as rep sniping,  But if you encounter someone copying your post word-for-word, then you can flag it and let the mods deal with it.

Comment: It was posted almost an hour after mine. The only difference was a ternary operator in the middle which printed something OP didn't ask for.

Comment: @User112638726 someone could be a slow typer :)